# Troubles with IE9 Hover

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover, internet-explorer-9

I have a very simple hover function that appears to work fine in everything except IE9 (possibly IE8 and below too, haven't tested them).

Non-IE browsers do this;

[image: Non IE]

IE9 does this;

[image: IE]

I suspect from reading various post that it *may* be to do with the `<a>` tag...but even that seems to be setup ok to me.
I'm a bit of a html/css/php noob, so it's probably something simple and obvious.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Relevant code;

**CSS File**

```
#nav {
width: 960px;
height: 40px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav a {
display: inline;
padding: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#nav a:hover {
background-color: #bababa;
height: 80px;
}
```

**PHP File**

```
<div id="nav">
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<a href="about.php">About</a>
<a href="#">Portfolio</a>
<a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
</div> <!-- end #nav -->
```

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/eX9xT/1/. You might be overriding it with another rule. Link to your site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe removing the "height: 80px" from #nav a:hover will get the browser to show what you want.

You are setting height value to an inline element and apparently IE supports that while other browsers do not.

Comment: I knew it was something simple and silly that I was overlooking!
Slightly off centre still, but it doesn't resize the page now, so that's close enough for me.

Comment: @FizzBuzz It is my understanding you are going for a menu here. You could use ul for that. See http://jsfiddle.net/6D38g/ for example.

Comment: Thanks for that AnPel! That's a neat site, I was unaware of.
Is using ul a better way of doing things? Does it render more consistently across all browsers?

Comment: Rendering consistently shouldn't really bother you once you get a good understanding of HTML and CSS. In my opinion, using ul or ol for menus is better markup semantically.